# PHP Divide variable into two different variables

Tags: php

I have this variable : `$lang['_city']`

I need to divide it in two portions.

One portion will be `$key == lang` and second portion will be `$ind == _city`

I think I can do it with some sort of `regexp` but I am not good with it.

Can you help me?

P.S. The above example is only a sample. I need an abstract function that will do it with any passed variable.. So for example, get whatever is before [ and cut the $, and then get whatever is inside [' '].. I know the logic but not the way to do it :)
Also the new values will have to be assigned each one to a variable as explained before.

Thanks

Comment: Is `$lang['_city']` a variable or a string? Your post says it's a variable but implies that it's a string.

Comment: So you have something like `$s = '$lang[\'_city\']';`, and you want to split up `$s`?

Comment: mh not really. I need to divide $lang['city'] in lang and city

Comment: You're contradicting yourself here. You say to consider it a string, but that's what I have given in my previous comment. Do you want to take the variable `$lang['city']` and determine that the name of the variable is `lang` and the key is `city`?

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = "\$foo['bar']";

preg_match('~^\$(?\'key\'[^\[]+)\[\'(?\'ind\'[^\']+)~', $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches['key'], $matches['ind']);
```

http://ideone.com/XaopX

Comment: It is ok but it implies I will have to work with the array now. Can we get a straight forward solution..? I am not that good with PHP yet

Answer (score 0):

Regexp for `preg_match` would be: `~^\$([^\[]+)\[\s*("[^"]+"|'[^']+')\s*\]$~` (you'll need to escape `'` or `"` when moving to string).

Than:

```
$key = $match[1];
$ind = substr( $match[2], 1, -1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not even need regexp here :)

```
$str = "\$lang['city']";
$tmp =  explode('[', $str);
$key = ltrim($tmp[0], '$');
$ind = trim($tmp[1], ']\'"');
echo $key . '=>' . $ind;
```

Starting from PHP 5.4 you could do it even shorter

```
$str = "\$lang['city']";
$key = ltrim(explode('[', $str)[0], '$');
$ind = trim(explode('[', $str)[1], ']\'"');
echo $key . '=>' . $ind;
```